# I got data from MySQL to show up in the jTable but I'm getting an Exception

Tags: java, jdbc, mysql-connector

Here's the code:

```java
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String PatientID = jtxtPatientID.getText();
        try {
            Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select *from patient where PatientID='" + PatientID + "'");
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            while(rs.first()){
                jlbPID.setVisible(false);
                jtxtPatientID.setEditable(false);
            }   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Error");
        }
    }
```

My code is going to the `catch` block, but I don't know why.

Comment: Your code isn't properly formatted.

Comment: Thank you, guy !

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll move my comments to an answer, it'd be appreciated if you mark it as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, answering your question, your problem is that `"select *from patient where PatientID='" + PatientID + "'"` is not a valid `SQL`statement, because the `*` and the `FROM` clause are together. Instead, add a space on it.

Just change:

```java
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select *from patient where PatientID='" + PatientID + "'");
```

with:

```java
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from patient where PatientID='" + PatientID + "'");
```

And, as a side note, just a mere recommendation: [**Don't use the `Statement` interface if your SQL has parameters**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), instead, [use the `PreparedStatement` interface](https://www.baeldung.com/java-statement-preparedstatement). Otherwise, your code will be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

And, please, change your `catch` blocks to someting which is able to log what's happening on your application. It will help you a lot when debugging. What I recommend you is, basically, this:

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Myclass.class);

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String PatientID = jtxtPatientID.getText();
        String sql = "select * from patient where PatientID=?";
        try {
            Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            st.setString(1, PatientID);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            while(rs.first()){
                jlbPID.setVisible(false);
                jtxtPatientID.setEditable(false);
            }   
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOG.error("Error while processing the SQL statement...", e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Error");
        }
    }
```

I used [log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html) for the logging purposes of this example.